# Why isn't Wireless IR Links used in drones for communication?

Tags: optical

Currently, in the war in Ukraine drones get jammed and the operator losses the ability to control the drone. The comm. signal is transmitted via radio waves even though much of the work these drones perform is looking for the enemy in the area (which should put the drone more or less in line of sight).

I'm curious to why IR Wireless links that are often used for high-speed LAN systems across buildings hasn't or can't be implemented to prevent jamming?

Based on a formular i found online an IR optical laser could send a signal multiple kilometers and be received. Why wouldn't this be a practical solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are various reasons IR is not a great choice, but chief among them is that IR links are line of sight since IR light does not pass through most objects without being absorbed, scattered or reflected. This is different than radio which (due to the much longer wavelength) can scatter through solid objects without too much loss.

IR-based communications might work if you were ok with having a drone directly above you, but especially for military applications usually the goal is to have the enemy under the drone, not the operator.